# On what factors should we opt Java or .Net technology for a windows application?

Tags: c#, java

I am quite aware of both java and C# .Net .when i try to create a new windows application which are the factors that decide which technology should be opted?
I know of one thing ,for great and faster UI development Visual studio helps a lot.

Comment: "...I know of one thing ,for great and faster UI development Visual studio helps a lot." How?

Comment: If you happen to know about visual studio you wouldn have asked this.

Comment: Might be... Yet you can point me to some resources which will help me to decide which UI development should i prefer for my latter projects.

Comment: Only great thing is ,it has a design work bench which helps you design your Windows User interface nothing else:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several factors I would consider...

What are your programmers used to working with already? What third party libraries are you likely to need, what's available on both platforms?

Does platform independence matter to you?

Would LinQ be advantageous?

If you're starting from scratch, costs for the platforms?

Both platforms have strong communities around them...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Persoanlly I wouldn't consider Mono in your decision - my own experience of it was that it the Winforms support was hopeless...

Admittedly this was a couple of years back though.

Comment: No problem Ravisha...

Also, if you don't already have Visual Studio, be sure to evaluate SharpDevelop (http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) before you commit to Visual Studio, if indeed that's the way you decide to go...

Also, I understand the Eclipse platform is looking at major improvements for working with Swing - including a GUI designer tool...

Comment: I am not aware of the progress going on in Eclispe.are there any major development plans to provide great UI design capability?i would be glad to hear that.:)
That might make java even more popular.

Comment: thaks again for enlightening with a new IDE.Will surely try it once.

Comment: Here's one Swing Designer - but others are available...

http://code.google.com/p/visualswing4eclipse/

Comment: The best GUI designer for Swing at the moment, is the one shipped with Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

Dotnet is pretty much native in Windows which obviously makes it more suited to writing Windows programs. Using Java in a Windows-only environment makes it much harder for you since it effectively just adds another unnecessary API layer.

You will soon realise that all integration points between your Java code and Windows are a bit problematic. For instance, creating installation programs, access file system, reading/writing the registry, starting/stopping services, task bar icons, using Windows GUI components (media player, IE...), help file system...

It all boils down to this imo: The Dotnet framework is much richer in terms of functionality than the Java dito, mainly becuase Java is cross-platform and thus needs a "one-size-fit-all" approach to its API. My experience is that you will only get frustrated trying to "emulate" a Windows native program in Java.

Comment: "creating installation programs, access file system, reading/writing the registry, starting/stopping services, task bar icons" is not a problem for java for last couple of years.
And .Net - the same "another-one" API layer, just more integrated in Windows - and sometimes - especially with old programs - this is a real headache: eg. .Net 2.0 DO NOT support programs, that were writen with .Net 1.1. Java do not have such problems. No matter which java you use - 1.2-1.5 - you can run it on 1.6.
So if project is long term - think about this too.

Comment: Well, you can do those things, but it is not as painless as in dotnet/VS for obvious reasons. Java may be good at certain things, but for writing native Windows programs... no, I don't think so.

Comment: Believe me - writing programs, which work with windows services - so f#cking work both in java and in C# (I mean real work: with installing service, upgrading it, reinstalling, checking correct security accounts and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Choose the one with which you are most familiar.  The two platforms are different enough that skills from one does not transfer easily to the other.

In any case, try making a trivial application in both your scenarios and see how it works for you.  The initial impression is important as it is probably indicative of how well the rest of the work will be.

Comment: +1 - this is (IMO) the only *universally* sound reason for choosing one over the other.

Comment: @Ravisha, more like putting a toe in the water.  It does not have to be more complicated than "Create a window sized 300x300 with the text 'Hello World' and an OK button".

Comment: I agree this will give u a abstract view but still i do not agree:)
Why becos creating a small form with few behavior wont be different ,You wont get that much idea about the difference in aproachs.I rule this out :)

Comment: @Ravisha, if your team makes the decision without doing this, you are doing so on incomplete data.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on what kind of windows application you want to build. If it's just a question of building a simple standalone application then, considering you know both languages equally well, I wouldn't hesitate and would go for a 100% microsoft solution, especially if you have to do specific things like accessing ActiveDirectory, the windows registry, etc.
Not that you can't do it in Java : you can always use AD through LDAP in Java for example, but the APIs are just "a bit" more complicated than the .Net ones (try to decode objectSIDs in Java without a few tricks).

Now if you have to build an enterprise app. I just feel that popular frameworks like Spring and Hibernate are always coming out after their Java counterparts (disclaimer : this is a personal opinion; I didn't do any research on this, thoroughly comparing frameworks in both languages, but that's just the feeling I have). I don't know how good the .Net implementations are though, so I don't have a point of view on that. I just remember writing .Net 2.0 apps and not liking ADO.Net at all.

My view is that the frameworks I like do exist in both languages, but they are first developed for Java, then ported to .Net.

Now I'm not the kind of developer trying to defend his favourite language over the others. If I don't have external constraints to develop, then I choose whatever language gets my app up and running faster and in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

...But with java you will have crossplatform application on scratch.
Also coding UI in java is not difficult - if you read some guides before and use some frameworks as swing application framework or SWT framework.

Comment: Well Mono runs fine on Linux and Mac OS too, so being cross platform isn't a reason to choose Java over C# (or any other .net language).

Comment: Why do .NET if you don't use the full potential?

Comment: Be honest - Mono is just struts, and... I do not see Mono on HP-UX :)

Comment: or AIX, which is the port we would need.

Answer (score 0):

If its Exclusively for Windows then .Net is best bet.

Comment: Can u point out the factors that make .Net best?Cos thats what my question is.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah for a pure cross platform application Java can't be beat, but if you can manage it Silverlight is a subset of WPF and a pretty compelling cross-platform proposition on its own.

Productivity-wise I think WPF has an edge as it has a nice XAML markup language that can be easily created with the built-in designer in VS.NET or integrates nicely with MS' suite of expression products.